# Как упростить код в android?

Tags: android, android-data-binding, butterknife

Всегда хотел узнать есть ли в андроид что-то типо аннотации?

вообщем чтобы получить clicklistner implements View.OnClickListener

Мне надо писать:

```
TextView text=(TextView)findviewbyid(R.id.text);
text.setonclicklistener(this);
```

Можно ли как то аннотацией заменить весь этот код? реально порой слишком много текста вознникает из за этого

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Есть такая замечательная вещь, как [ButterKnife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/). Она создана как раз для этих целей. Также значительно уменьшает количество кода, и упрощает разработку. Попробуйте

В вашем случае это будет выглядеть вот так:

```
class ExampleActivity extends Activity {
  @BindView(text) TextView text;

  @Override public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.simple_activity);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
  }

  @OnClick(R.id.text)
  public void submit() {
   // TODO something
  }
}
```

Comment: А есть плагин в Android Studio. Чтобы когда кидаешь через setContentView. Он сам тебе создает все эти TextView ImageView?

Comment: Не знаю, мне кажется это не совсем нужная  вещь. Попробуйте поискать прямо в плагинах идеи

Comment: Почему же)). Допустим когда вы класс в андроид студии созадете вы пишите имя класс и создается файл с 

`package com.fdsf.scdfdffd;

/**
 * Created by fsdfs.
 */
public class asdsaad {

}
`

А бывают и классы с уже готовыми 2 страницами. Вам бы понравилось если бы все это было бы пустым. И вы каждый раз одно  и тоже бы писали. Просто одно и тоже, одно и тоже.

Comment: Вы путаете понятия шаблонов и динамической подгрузки кода. Во всяком случае, если у меня актимти состоит из 10 textview в которых статический текст, а используется в коде только 1, то зачем мне все 10 экземпляров textview? Это вопрос для холивара и думаю обсуждать его можно очень долго)